# OpenCv error can't open camera through video capture

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, ubuntu, video-capture

I was using my cam through opencv and suddenly after restarting I ran my code it shows below error:

```
[ WARN:0] global /io/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (802) open VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L: can't open camera by index 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 20, in <module>
    retval, buffer_img = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.2) /io/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp:877: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !image.empty() in function 'imencode'
```

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  # here it throws an error


import json
while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    retval, buffer_img = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)

    resdata = base64.b64encode(buffer_img)

    resdata = "data:image/png;base64,"+ str(resdata.decode("utf-8"))
    PARAMS = {'image': resdata}

    # Our operations on the frame come here
    #gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I also tried with `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)` but then it shows can't find camera

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 23):

I got the same error. Try changing 0 to -1

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(-1)
```

This solved the issue.

Comment: your got error cause -1 index. -1 index meaning last element of list. i recommend you. you may use 0 if you have webcam.

Answer (score 19):

I got the same problem when I created more than one instance of the cv2.VideoCapture(0). So check if your code contains multiple initializations or sections which call cv2.VideoCapture(0) more than once. I was facing this problem while running the flask server in debug mode because it called cv2.VideoCapture(0) twice.

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap2 = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:

    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Error:

```
python3 debugCamera.py 
[ WARN:0] global /io/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (887) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video0): can't open camera by index
```

Comment: You try to open a camera two times. When a hardware ingress a work then it don't allow outer command at same time .

Answer (score 15):

Most likely a permission issue on `/dev/video0`.

Check if you are part of "video" group.
`id -a`

if you don't see video in your group list add
`sudo usermod -a -G video`

for Ubuntu users:(20.04)
`sudo usermod -a -G video $LOGNAME`

Logout and log back in and try it.

Comment: It worked for me to run a X application inside docker container. I have also needed to install v4l-utils. Just like [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@petehouston/install-v4l-utils-on-debian-based-distros-d4f5c2fdcf61).

Comment: I am using a rdp user for the xrdp server on the raspberry 4, and giving permissions was the solution, Thanks. For the pi, must be sudo usermod -a -G video $LOGNAME

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem,
Just change 0 to 1,then to -1 and back again to 0.
Don't know why this worked for me.

Comment: it makes no sense whatsoever , but it worked for me too

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution in https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/19527 where the video capture is inside the function instead of outside. That worked for me (ubuntu)

```
def frame_generation():

camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0) #resolved, correct position

while(True):
```

Comment: I don't know why but it works for me, no other solution worked

Comment: Didn't solve this problem for me, but this is much neater and more logical than leaving it within the loop. So I've done it anyway,

Answer (score 3):

```
video = cv2.VideoCapture(0,cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I will not go to that part What you are trying to do, here is just a block of code that can open your camera every time you run it,

python: 3.7.3

OpenCV: 4.1.0

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:

    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0), its not working,its giving me the error I mentioned in the beginning

Comment: what kind of camera are you using? Laptop default camera(0), external camera(1-....), just change the value 0-... and see what happen.

Comment: I have used (-1) it gives can't find camera device

Comment: just change it 0 to 1 or 2 or 3 , if it is not work then problem maybe you python or openCV version. you can reinstall it and see what happen, just a quick suggestion

Comment: did all sort of things still can't fix,I think there is ubuntu compatibility issue otherwise it should run.

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered the same issue and attempted several methods like `cv2.VideoCapture(-1)` or `cv2.VideoCapture(1)` but without much success.

I succeeded after reading [this article](https://manivannan-ai.medium.com/live-webcam-flask-opencv-python-26a61fee831) and **disabling debug-mode**

Comment: There is nothing about disabling debug-mode in the article. Looks like a spam.

Comment: @LeonidMednikov I think the author remove some information from his article, I solved the issue by this way at that time. If this solution is obsolete you should correct the answer, downvoting cannot help other people.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same problem. Just changed it to 1 and it was perfectly working. I guess it's related to the number of camera devices you have used.

For example, I guess I have Iruin external camera as my first option which I didn't connect this time.

Here is the error and corrected code.

```
global /tmp/pip-req-build-f51eratu/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (890) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video0): can't open camera by index
```

Code to change:

```
vid = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

The OP appears to be operating on a Raspberry PI. Raspberry is moving to a new system to manage cameras, so when the user upgrades the OS via `sudo apt-get upgrade` the camera system gets the new library and the legacy camera system is disabled. To enable the legacy camera system again, try

```
sudo raspi-config
```

Then select

```
3 Interface Options    Configure connections to peripherals
```

then select

```
I1 Legacy Camera Enable/disable legacy camera support
```

and follow the directions to enable and then reboot.

Of course, this patch will only work for so long, as the legacy system has been deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I just reconnected cam to the usb port, and then it was solved! I think this error is caused by closing the window in the wrong way. Please check if there is any exception on the terminal right after closing the window.

Comment: I don't think answers to software problems should include hardware/manual solutions. I might be as helpful as "restart your program" when you stumble upon an error somewhere

Answer (score 1):

For Linux, make sure OpenCV is built using the WITH_V4L (with video for linux).

Comment: Check this easily with: `print(cv2.getBuildInformation())`

Answer (score 1):

I've also had this problem on Ubuntu

I've solved this by these comands

sudo adduser username video
sudo usermod -a -G video username

username - it is the name of your device

than write

id -a

and copy index from ()

for me it is 1000

so than just write:

camera = cv2.VideoCapture(1000)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Are you sure this answers the question at the top of the page? It doesn't appear to be related. Please read [answer].

Answer (score 1):

Tried every anwser but only changing camera id from -1 to 1 and then back to 0 worked.

Answer (score 0):

I have do everytime after restart or unplug usb camera and replug

chmod 777 /dev/video0

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is still an issue.
In my case, I was getting the same error until I unplugged and plugged the usb camera. Even if I reboot, the error happened.

It's similar to someone said: my camera was already been captured.
The problem is that it was not used by my script, so it was hard to identify.

A few days before the issue, I installed the motion library, but just to test something and I didn't use it anymore. The motion starts at boot, so the camera was being captured by the service. That's why only the unplug-plug worked.

I uninstalled the library, and the error was gone.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me as other contributors noted was to simply unplug the camera from the USB port and plug it back in, while the Raspberry PI Ubuntu OS was running.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is for Mac only.

1. I used PyCharm rather than Anaconda.  I couldn't figure out how to get Mac system to recognize the camera on Anaconda, but PyCharm, after running the code will ask for permission.  Also, the opencv version for Anaconda is out of date and doesn't have some of the features of PyCharm.
2. Under System Settings, Privacy and Security, Camera make sure the camera is enabled for PyCharm.
3. The HD FaceTime camera is `cap=cv2.VideoCapture(2)` not `(0)`.  You will find that `cv2.VideoCapture(0).isOpened()` is `True`, but the `ret`, `image=cap.read()` will return `ret` as `False` if it is the wrong camera.
4. if it is still not working, try adding this:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(2)  
cap.release()   
cap= cv2.VideoCapture(2)
```

It could be that you have an open window that the program believes is opened.

Comment: `cv2.VideoCapture(0)` would try to open camera with driver node /dev/video0 from V4L backend. It may work if there is such a camera node that provides a suitable format. You would have to manage where your platform assigns different cameras. You may use `v4l2-ctl -d0 --list-formats-ext` for available modes from camera 0. Depending on available formats, from opencv you may use V4L or gstreamer backend for getting frames.

Answer (score 0):

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

The 0, 1, 2, etc digit we pass through the VideoCapture function is the device index given to the device from the os.
As the device index is assigned by os, The number would be at random. So to find out the device index of your camera, in linux open command line

```
sudo apt-get install v4l-utils
```

Once installed use

```
v4l2-ctl --list-devices
```

to list all connected device something like this

```
Integrated Camera (usb-0000:00:3b.0-1.2):
    /dev/video0
```

Comment: You can also pass the device name: `cap = cv2.VideoCapture('/dev/video0')`

Answer (score -1):

This issue is due to the interruption. Try to end the execution with the key 'q' for example, don't close the window suddenly.

I solved the same issue by opening terminal again and execute the same script again.