# OpenCv can't open camera by index

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu

### OS

Ubuntu 20.04

### OPENCV Version

4.4.0

### Language

Python 3.8.5

#### Code and prob description:

I am trying to learn and play with OPENCV, but I am encountering a weird problem. I can not use web cam with opencv. Web cam is working with `Cheese` Application. I have tried multiple solutions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59371075/opencv-error-cant-open-camera-through-video-capture) answer, but none work.

I inspected code line by line, and got that error is on `cv2.VideoCapture(index)`

```py
In [1]: import cv2

In [2]: cv2.VideoCapture(0)
[ WARN:0] global /tmp/pip-req-build-a3np7pha/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (893) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video0): can't open camera by index
Out[2]: <VideoCapture 0x7f1773353550>

In [3]: cv2.VideoCapture(-1)
[ WARN:0] global /tmp/pip-req-build-a3np7pha/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (893) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video0): can't open camera by index
Out[3]: <VideoCapture 0x7f1773304990>

In [4]: cv2.VideoCapture(1)
[ WARN:0] global /tmp/pip-req-build-a3np7pha/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (893) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video1): can't open camera by index
Out[4]: <VideoCapture 0x7f17733048b0>
```

Comment: First connect your usb camera, test it with windows app camera if it work that's ok. Then try open it with opencv.. if don't work it: `cv2.VideoCapture(0)` try it `cv2.VideoCapture(1)`

Comment: @FreddyDaniel I have a built-in webcam, that is already working.

Comment: ok man good luck.

Comment: Did you find any success?

Comment: What I remember is that you have to close all the windows by Opencv correctly first. i.e cv2.destroyallwindows and then this might work. Any other application must not be using webcam at that tine. Restarting might help;