# What is the difference between cv2.videocapture(1) and cv2.videocapture(0)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, python-3.9

```
import cv2

cap= cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret,frame= cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('Our live sketch',frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1)==13:
        break

cap.release()
```

When I use  `cv2.VideoCapture(1)`, the programs shows error but the program works properly if I use `cv2.VideoCapture(0)`

Answer (score 4):

That's the index of the camera it is used to select different cameras if you have more than one attached. By default `0` is your main one.

Comment: So if I had two cameras, my index would have been cv2.VideoCapture(1)?

Comment: If you want to use your second camera yes.

Answer (score 1):

I have answered it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77514023/8609909)
0, 1, 2 or any other number is device id assigned by os and is prone to change