# can't open camera by index

Tags: python, opencv, webcam

OS: ubuntu 18.04

```
class VideoThread(QThread):
    change_pixmap_signal = pyqtSignal(np.ndarray)

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self._run_flag = True

    def run(self) -> None:
        # capture from web cam
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        while self._run_flag:
            ret, cv_img = cap.read()
            if ret:
                self.change_pixmap_signal.emit(cv_img)
        # shut down capture system
        cap.release()
```

I used the above code to capture images using a webcam, but I got some errors like below mentioned

i tried `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)` & `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(-1)` both methods also failed

Now how to resolve this issue?

```
[ WARN:0] global /io/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (887) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video0): can't open camera by index
```

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59371075/opencv-error-cant-open-camera-through-video-capture#61817613 ?

Comment: if you have the rep, you should flag this question as a duplicate.

Comment: what makes you think your computer even has a camera? did you try accessing it with any other program?

Comment: Put this in  self.run() in def __init__(self) -> None: