# Java Opencv is unable to access webcam 'can't open camera by index'

Tags: java, opencv

I am trying to use the opencv library in Java to take pictures using the webcam (Logitech C270). In my code, I have the following:

```
    VideoCap(){
        cap = new VideoCapture(0);
        cap.open(0);
    }
```

Which is the function that creates the new video capture device. Running the program gives the following error:

```
[ WARN:0@0.198] global cap_v4l.cpp:003 open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video0): can't open camera by index
[Error:0@0.201] global obsensor_uvc_stream_channel.cpp:156 getStreamChannelGroup Camera index out of range
```

I have tried placing various values inside the VideoCapture constructor (-1, 0, , 1) all of them give the same error. I have confirmed that Opencv compiled with V4L2.

Running v4l2-ctl --list-devices confirms that the webcam is detected, and I also ran cheese and was able to get video input

Following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1110766/videoio-errorv4l-cant-open-camera-by-index-0) suggestion I ran this command: sudo chmod 777 /dev/video0, which did not solve the problem.

I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64490341/16743764) suggestion which also did not affect the issue

Comment: And you already read through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59371075/opencv-error-cant-open-camera-through-video-capture?

Comment: I have, and running the suggested commands to fix permission issues has not solved the issue.

Comment: Then remember to add that to your post, too. Let people know what you already tried so they don't ask you to repeat something you already ruled out.